# Future II Simple in Japanese

Tags: grammar, future, past

How can you express something like "Tomorrow I will have finished my work" or "Because I have to do hard word tomorrow, I will be very tired in the evening"?

明日、仕事を絶対終えたようとする。　？
明日、にくい仕事があるから、夜にとても疲れしまっているようになる（なりそうだ？）。　？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is just the future perfect, the meaning of your English sentence though is a bit ambiguous.

- 明日になるともう休みに入っている（だろう・はず・と思う）
- 明日になるともう仕事は終わっている（だろう・はず・と思う）
- 明日になるともうやることは全部終わっている（だろう・はず・と思う）

Your second example is just the simple future "Because A, will B".

- 大変な仕事が待っているから、明日、退勤して帰ったらもうくたくただろうなぁ

Comment: Future 2 Simple apparently is the same as Future Perfect. The second example was kinda bad. What about _Because I have work all day tomorrow, I will not have done my homework for the evening class_ ?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the situations in which you want to say those but here are some natural-sounding sentences.

For Sentence 1:

> 「明日には仕事を終えるつもりです（or 終えるつもりでいます）。」 Plain active voice.

If you absolutely must use 「絶対」, place it right in front of the 仕事 or 終える.

You could also say:

> 「明日には（or までには）仕事を終わらせるつもりです。」 I used a causative 終わらせる here.

For Sentence 2:

> 「明日は大変な仕事があるので、晩にはとても疲れていると思います。」
>
> 「明日はきつい仕事があるので、夜までにはかなり疲れていると思う。」

You cannot say 「にくい仕事」.  You need a verb in front of にくい like「やりにくい仕事」.

Comment: While にくい is strange as the poster used it, it doesn't have to be used like you suggest either: この猫、ほんま**にくい**奴やわ. (＝かわいい・あいくるしい)

Comment: it doesn't have to be used like you suggest either>>> え、どういう意味？l'électeurさんが間違えてるって意味ですか？

Comment: 「にくい」を「かわいい」って意味で使うのって、古くないですかね。。。「にくいね～三菱！」とか、わざと古い言葉を使ってる気がしませんか。

Comment: 間違ってるというのじゃなくて、むしろ必ずしも他の動詞の連用形に付ける必要があるとは言い切れないのだということです。